# Estan bien los resultados?

Tags: python

Estoy realizando ejercicios en python de funciones recursivas, pero el problema es que no entiendo como llegan a esos resultados.
Este es el ejercicio:
*

> a) lucca(0) = 2, lucca(1) = 1,lucca(n) = lucca(n − 1) + lucca(n − 2)
> para n ≥ 2 - b) pell(0) = 0, pell(1) = 1, pell(n) = 2 × pell(n − 1) +
> pell(n − 2) para n ≥ 2 - c) jacob(0) = 0, jacob(1) = 1, jacob(n) = jacob(n
> − 1) + 2 × jacob(n − 2) para n ≥ 2*

Por lo tanto, esta son mis funciones:

```
#A
def lucca(n):
    """ Diseño:
    Numero: Natural
    Signatura:
        Nat Nat -> Nat
    Proposito:
        Calcular la suma de un numero menos 1 
        y el numero menos 2 
        lucca(0)=2 
        lucca(1)=1 
        lucca(5)=11 
    """
    if n == 0:
        return 2 
    elif n == 1:
```

Entiendo que pude haberlas realizado de forma incorrecta, pero estoy seguro que las hice bien, solo que no entiendo como llegan a los resultados. Por ejemplo,

```
jacob(8) == 85
```

Alguien podria explicarme sus razonamientos? Hice el ejerciciom pero no entiendo las funciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que puedo entender de los ejercicios, te dan las condiciones de parada, que son los primeros resultados(lucca(0) = 2, lucca(1) = 1 ...) y luego el algoritmo recursivo ( lucca(n) = lucca(n-1) + lucca(n-2) ).

Esto es un diseño típico de algoritmos recursivos: tienen condiciones de paradas que garantizan que no se ejecutan infinitamente y el propio algoritmo.

El primer ejercicio quedaria así:

```
def luca(n):
    if n < 0:
        return -1
    if n == 0:
        return 2 
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return lucca(n-1) + lucca(n-2)
```

El tercer inciso:

```
def jacob(n):
    if n < 0:
        return -1
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return jacob(n-1) + 2 * jacob(n-2)
```

La solucion de `jacob(8)` es, efectivamente, 85. Para calcularla se calcula de esta manera:

```
jacob(8) = jacob(7) + 2*jacob(6)
```

Para poder calcular los valores de `jacob(7)` y `jacob(6)` hay que calcular los valores menores hasta llegar a las condiciones de paradas: `jacob(1)` y `jacob(0)`

```
jacob(7) = jacob(6) + 2*jacob(5)
jacob(6) = jacob(5) + 2*jacob(4)
jacob(5) = jacob(4) + 2*jacob(3)
jacob(4) = jacob(3) + 2*jacob(2)
jacob(3) = jacob(2) + 2*jacob(1)
jacob(2) = jacob(1) + 2*jacob(0)
jacob(1) = 1
jacob(0) = 0
```

Luego que tienes los valores de 0 y 1, sustituyes los resultados hasta llegar a  la ejecucion de `jacob(8)`:

```
jacob(0) = 0
jacob(1) = 1
jacob(2) = jacob(1) + 2*jacob(0) = 1 + 2*0   = 1
jacob(3) = jacob(2) + 2*jacob(1) = 1 + 2*1   = 3
jacob(4) = jacob(3) + 2*jacob(2) = 3 + 2*1   = 5
jacob(5) = jacob(4) + 2*jacob(3) = 5 + 2*3   = 11
jacob(6) = jacob(5) + 2*jacob(4) = 11 + 2*5  = 21
jacob(7) = jacob(6) + 2*jacob(5) = 21 + 2*11 = 43
jacob(8) = jacob(7) + 2*jacob(6) = 43 + 2*21 = 85
```